# Where can I see the current size of the bitcoin blockchain?

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am tying to understand the concept of the bitcoin blockchain, from what I understand everybody owns a full copy of the bitcoin blockchain, but is it possible to see the current size somewhere without having "checked it out/cloned it"?

And are there any backups being made? I know it's distributed and everyone owns a full copy - kinda like with a git repository - but is it also backed up on centralized servers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use this website:

https://blockchain.info/charts/blocks-size

Comment: Ah yes, so currently around 135 GB and a pretty step rate of growth, in a couple of years this will not be feasible to work with I guess?

Comment: @u123 Welcome to Bitcoin! You've stumbled directly into the scaling debate, quite probably the most contentious part of the Bitcoin protocol. Growth of the blockchain is one of the arguments towards keeping the block size limited.